# How to set ifconfig for move tag use in xml magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, configuration, ifconfig

I have stuck the set configuration with ifconfig element for move tag. I was tried but no luck. you can see below code where i want to put ifconfig element:

```
<move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="catalog-leftnav-top" before = "-"/>
```

I just want to set condition when extension is disable from configuration than this move tag should not working.

if you have any alternate solution please provide to me. It will too much helpful for me and also others.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move some elements only when extension is installed and enabled you should add this `<move>` declaration inside XML of this extension. This way extension's XML will not be considered when building layout and therefore this `<move>` won't happen.